# showing images on website responsive

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoXnR.jpg)

i want to add 4 types of this images (same size 1656 x 2416) in my website but i want it to get smaller and responsive on the website and side by side

```
<div>
<div><img src="img/menu.jpeg"  alt="menu1"></div>
<div><img src="img/menu2.jpeg" alt="menu2"></div>
<div><img src="img/menu1.jpeg" alt="menu2"></div>
<div><img src="img/menu3.jpeg" alt="menu2"></div>
```

Comment: if you are using bootstrap, just add `class="img-responsive"`

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap, have you even tried to read the docs? https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images

Comment: I guess you really need to read the manual for bootstrap as you don't even have your row or col classes on those divs

Comment: BS4 uses img-fluid NOT img-responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style the divs as float:left and set height to a reasonable size so that all 4 images can fit side by side when img-responsive is specified as suggested by @Moslem.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/menu.jpeg"  alt="menu1">
```